# How can we store protected array values in php variables

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to access a protected array tree. I had tried many ways to get the data from the tree. The array is stored in a variable called `$printers`. I had tried a normal approach like using array index values like `echo $printers[0].printers` etc, but no luck. Could anyone please guide me to how to access this protected array tree?

```
Array
(
    [0] => PrintNode\Printer Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 69416933
            [computer:protected] => PrintNode\Computer Object
                (
                    [id:protected] => 123456
                    [name:protected] => DESKTOP
                    [inet:protected] => 0.0.0.0
                    [inet6:protected] => 
                    [hostname:protected] => Controlroom@DESKTOP
                    [version:protected] => 4.23.1
                    [jre:protected] => 
                    [systemInfo:protected] => 
                    [acceptOfflinePrintJobs:protected] => 
                    [createTimestamp:protected] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2020-04-16 11:23:56.595000
                            [timezone_type] => 2
                            [timezone] => Z
                        )
                [state:protected] => connected
            )

        [name:protected] => ZJ
        [description:protected] => ZJ-80 11.3.0.1
        [capabilities:protected] => Array
            (
                [bins] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Automatically Select
                        [1] => Manual Paper Feed
                    )

                [collate] => 1
                [color] => 
                [copies] => 9999
                [dpis] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 203x203
                    )

                [duplex] => 
                [extent] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 2099
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 32759
                            )

                    )

                [medias] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [nup] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [1] => 2
                        [2] => 4
                        [3] => 6
                        [4] => 9
                        [5] => 16
                    )

                [papers] => Array
                    (
                        [ZPrinter Paper(80 x 210mm)] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 2099
                            )

                        [ZPrinter Paper(80 x 297mm)] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 2970
                            )

                        [ZPrinter Paper(80 x 3276mm)] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 32759
                            )

                        [ZPrinter Paper(80(72) x 210mm)] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 2099
                            )

                        [ZPrinter Paper(80(72) x 297mm)] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 2970
                            )

                        [ZPrinter Paper(80(72) x 3276mm)] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 32759
                            )

                    )

                [printrate] => 
                [supports_custom_paper_size] => 
            )

        [default:protected] => 
        [createTimestamp:protected] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2020-04-29 13:53:39.527000
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => Z
            )

        [state:protected] => offline
    )

[1] => PrintNode\Printer Object
    (
        [id:protected] => 123456789
        [computer:protected] => PrintNode\Computer Object
            (
                [id:protected] => 1234566
                [name:protected] => DESKTOP
                [inet:protected] => 192.168.1.2
                [inet6:protected] => 
                [hostname:protected] => Controlroom@DESKTOP
                [version:protected] => 4.23.1
                [jre:protected] => 
                [systemInfo:protected] => 
                [acceptOfflinePrintJobs:protected] => 
                [createTimestamp:protected] => DateTime Object
                    (
                        [date] => 2020-04-16 11:23:56.595000
                        [timezone_type] => 2
                        [timezone] => Z
                    )

                [state:protected] => connected
            )

        [name:protected] => ZJ-80(copy of 2)
        [description:protected] => ZJ-80 11.3.0.1
        [capabilities:protected] => Array
            (
                [bins] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Automatically Select
                        [1] => Manual Paper Feed
                    )

                [collate] => 1
                [color] => 
                [copies] => 9999
                [dpis] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 203x203
                    )

                [duplex] => 
                [extent] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 2099
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 32759
                            )

                    )

                [medias] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [nup] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [1] => 2
                        [2] => 4
                        [3] => 6
                        [4] => 9
                        [5] => 16
                    )

                [papers] => Array
                    (
                        [ZPrinter Paper(80 x 210mm)] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 2099
                            )

                        [ZPrinter Paper(80 x 297mm)] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 2970
                            )

                        [ZPrinter Paper(80 x 3276mm)] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 32759
                            )

                        [ZPrinter Paper(80(72) x 210mm)] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 2099
                            )

                        [ZPrinter Paper(80(72) x 297mm)] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 2970
                            )

                        [ZPrinter Paper(80(72) x 3276mm)] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 719
                                [1] => 32759
                            )

                    )

                [printrate] => 
                [supports_custom_paper_size] => 
            )

        [default:protected] => 1
        [createTimestamp:protected] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2020-04-29 14:34:00.787000
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => Z
            )

        [state:protected] => offline
    )
```

)

I need to access the values, the hostname:protected and name:protected and paper's 1st element.

Comment: Protected Variables prevent you from doing exactly that, showing them.  Though how did you get this var_dump?

Comment: @Forbs I use this function to print the above array tree  function prettyPrint($a) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($a);
    echo "</pre>";
}

echo prettyPrint($printers);

Comment: Not used these classes before, but have you tried `echo $printers[0].computer.hostname;`, or perhaps see what `echo $printers;` gives you.

Comment: @NigelRen the above is the output of echo $printers

Comment: Sorry - it looks more like the output of something line `print_r($printers)`.

Comment: Check object if has methods to print its parameters.

Comment: I always access OBJECT using -> notation so it's `$printers[0]->computer->hostname`is the dot notation new?